# Putting variable table column into permanent table, but get error that it isn't a scalar variable

Tags: sql, set

```
update autos
set autos.risico = @tbldeelnames.risico
```

Get an error on @tbldeelnames

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Your code is not valid SQL in any database (that I'm familiar with) so sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

Scalar value refers to a single value.

```
UPDATE a
  SET a.riscio = t.risico
FROM @autos a
JOIN @tbldeelnames t on a.key = t.key
```

OR:

```
DECLARE @risico INT = 0;
```

[Do stuff to find value of risico and set it]

```
UPDATE Autos SET risico = @risico
```

Your update statement assumes there's only one autos.risico and only one @tbldeelname.risico, which means you don't need tables to hold the value(s), and your update statement makes no sense in that context.

If your @tbldeelnames contains more than one record, then you need to specify *WHICH* record to use from @tbldeelnames. And, which record from @autos to update, otherwise all records in @autos will be updated with the value from the chosen record in @tbldeellnames.